# Null data in mongoDB when post data in postman via x-www-form-urlencoded API NodeJS

Tags: node.js, api, postman

I'm making a restful API using nodejs, when I enter data on a postman with the method of x-www-form-urlencoded data on mongodb is empty. when i use raw in the data postman is entered. what's wrong? Thank you. This is my code. Please Help Me..

```
 App.js
        var express = require('express');
        var mongoose = require('mongoose');
        var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
        var methodOverride = require('method-override');
        var morgan = require('morgan');
        var path = require('path');
        var passport = require('passport');
        var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
        var http = require('http');
        var logger = require('morgan');
        var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
        var session = require('express-session');
        var multer = require('multer');
        var errorhandler = require('errorhandler');

        var app = express();

        app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
        app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
        app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

        app.use(logger('dev'));
        app.use(methodOverride());
        app.use(session({
          resave: true,
          saveUninitialized: true,
          secret: 'uwotm8'
        }));
        app.use(bodyParser.json());
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
          extended: true
        }));



        app.use(multer());
        app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
        app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'bower_component')));
        app.use(passport.initialize());
        app.use(passport.session());

        var indexRoute = require('./routes/IndexRoute');
        var userRoute = require('./routes/UserRoute');
        var loginRoute = require('./routes/LoginRoute');

        app.use('/', indexRoute);
        app.use('/api/user', userRoute);
        app.use('/', loginRoute);

        app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
          res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin || '*');
          res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Request-With, Content-Type');
          res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
          next();
        });

        mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Belajar', function(err, res) {
          if (err) {
            console.log('Koneksi mongodb gagal');
          } else {
            console.log('Koneksi mongodb berhasil');
          }
        });

        if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
          app.use(errorhandler());
        }

        var server = http.createServer(app);
        server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
          console.log('Server jalan di port : ' + app.get('port'));
        });


Route

    UserRoute.js
        var express = require('express');
        var mongoose = require('mongoose');
        var User = require('../models/User');
        var router = express.Router();
        var getUser = function(req, res, next) {
          User.find(function(err, users) {
            if (err) return res.json(err);

            return res.json({
              user: users
            });
          });
        };

        var getUserObject = function(req, res, next) {
          User.findOne({
            email: req.params.email
          }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) return res.json(err);

            if (!user) return res.json({
                info: '404',
                pesan: 'Data tidak ada'
              });

            return res.json(user);

          });
        };

        var saveUser = function(req, res, next) {
          var user = new User({
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password,
            nama: req.body.nama,
            noHp: req.body.noHp,
            tanggalLahir: req.body.tanggalLahir,
            role: req.body.role
          });

          user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) return res.json(err);
            return res.json({
              success: 'true',
              pesan: 'Data Tersimpan'
            });

          });

        };

        var editUser = function(req, res, next) {
          return User.update({
            email: req.params.email
          }, req.body, function(err) {
            if (err) return res.json(err);

            return res.json({
              success: 'true',
              pesan: 'Data Berhasil di edit'
            });
          });
        };

        var deleteUser = function(req, res, next) {
          return User.remove({
            email: req.params.email
          }, function(err) {

            if (err) return res.json(err);

            return res.json({
              success: 'true',
              pesan: 'Data Berhasil di hapus'
            });
          });
        }

        router.get('/', getUser);
        router.get('/find/:email', getUserObject);
        router.post('/save', saveUser);
        router.put('/update/:email', editUser);
        router.delete('/delete/:email', deleteUser);

        module.exports = router;


Model

    User.js
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var User = new Schema(
      {
        email: {
          type: 'String',
          require: true
        },
        password: {
          type: 'String',
          require: true
        },
        nama: {
          type: 'String',
          require: true
        },
        noHp: {
          type: 'String',
          require: true
        },
        tanggalLahir: {
          type: 'String',
          require: true
        },
        role: {
          type: 'String',
          require: true
        }
      },
      {
        collection: 'tb_user'
      }
    );

    module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);

package.json
{
  "name": "Belajar-Express",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "lalala",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.12.3",
    "connect": "^3.3.5",
    "ejs": "^2.3.1",
    "errorhandler": "^1.3.5",
    "express": "^4.12.3",
    "express-session": "^1.11.1",
    "method-override": "^2.3.2",
    "mongoose": "^4.0.2",
    "morgan": "^1.5.2",
    "multer": "^0.1.8",
    "passport": "^0.2.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: not empty but null in mongodb